# Trouble with global variables

Tags: jquery, variables

See the jfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/dirturban/0nq4zLen/1/

Otherwise, could someone tell me why my `var text_length` isn't working?

Code below:

```
var text_length = $('#textarea').val().length;
var video_length = text_length / 920;
var totalPrice = video_length * 2750;

$('#textarea').keyup(function () {
    $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_length + ' minutes');
});

$('button').click(function () {
    $('#price').text('$' + totalPrice + '.00');
});
```

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/0nq4zLen/2/

Comment: you are not getting value of text_lenght inside your keyup fucntion.

Comment: @user1661677 did the fiddle help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your **vars** inside your keyup function as

```
$('#textarea').keyup(function() {
    var text_length = $('#textarea').val().length;
    var video_length = text_length;
    var totalPrice = video_length;
    $('#textarea_feedback').html(video_length + ' minutes');

});
```

Now your vars are given new values on each keyup, also make sure you set **var** values before you put the html in the div

Before they were only getting values on document ready so for all the javascript knew your **text_length** var was always 0